# what is a valid handle for Matlab?

Tags: debugging, matlab, handle

I am newbie with Matlab. I am learning through the Matlab Documentation. At these moments, I am doing the example ["A GUI to Set Simulink Model Parameters"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f6-8865.html).
At the section "Closing the GUI" of the mentioned one, it appears the following code for the `Close` button callback:

```
function CloseButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)   
% Close the GUI and any plot window that is open  
if isfield(handles,'PlotFigure') && ...  
      ishandle(handles.PlotFigure),  
   close(handles.PlotFigure);  
end  
close(handles.F14ControllerEditor);
```

I am trying to understand what a valid handles is by parsing the behaviour of 
the handle `handles.PlotFigure`. I have inserted a breakpoint in the line number 
four of the code above and I have run the program in debugging mode. After doing that, my conclusion is:
- A valid handle (in this case a Handle Graphics Object called `handles.PlotFigure`) is an object which has not been deleted (closed) by some command.

However, I do not understand why the handle field `handles.PlotFigure` remains inside the handles structure and it has not been deleted.
Another surprise I found out while I was debugging was that the Variable Editor said "No valid plots for handles.PlotFigure{1,1}". I neither understand this because the figure for handles.PlotFigure did exist.

I would be thankful if someone run the example and can explain me my doubts.

Comment: For information on handles try this short video from Mathworks: http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2008/04/17/advanced-matlab-handles-and-other-inputs-to-guide-callbacks/

Comment: I would like someone tries to run the mentioned example and answers my doubts

Comment: I don't have Simulink so I can't reproduce your findings. If you are still unsure you can try posting a question at www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/

Comment: You do not need Simulink, only Matlab. Thank you back for your advice. Cheers.